# Difference between two date strings in java

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate difference between two date strings both of which are taken from user through a html form in format (yyyy/MM/dd)
Code:

```
public boolean diffDate() throws ParseException
 {
     date1 = getissuedate();
     date2 = getduedate();
         Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
Date date_old = formatter1.parse(date1);
Date date_new = formatter2.parse(date2);
long milis1 = date_old.getTime();
long milis2 = date_new.getTime();

long diff = milis2 - milis1;       

    if( diff<3 || diff>3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {       
        return false;
    }       
 }
```

Now am using an if condition to report error in my webpage if difference between the date is not equal to 3.
Code:

```
try {
        if(diffDate())
        {
            errors.add("duedate", new ActionMessage("error.duedate.required"));
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IssueBookForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

where error.duedate.required is mapped to "check date"

So, the issue is "check date" error is printed for any value of both date string.

Comment: You don't need two formatters for that.

Comment: @Pablo : it doesn't matters I removed the second formatter but issue is still there....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll never get a difference of exactly 3 *milliseconds* between two dates gotten from a yyyy/MM/dd formatted string (maximum accuracy will be 24 hours)

if you want 3 days difference use `24*60*60*1000` for a factor to scale the values

Answer (score 2):

You're testing if two dates differ by 3 milliseconds, which will almost always be true.  If you really want 3 days, the value should be 3*86400*1000.  If you care about what happens with leap-seconds and daylight-savings-time changes, then the problem gets more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition diff<3 || diff>3 is equivalent to diff != 3 and diff is expressed in milliseconds. This expression will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse dates with a resolution of 1 day, i.e. 86.000.000 milliseconds, you will never get a situation where they are exactly 3 ms different.

getTime() returns the time in ms since "the start of the epoch", so it returns milliseconds, or 1/1000 s.

```
diff < 3 || diff > 3
```

is the same as

```
diff != 3
```

If you want to detect dates which are exactly 3 days different, you could divide the number of millis by the number of ms/day before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Calendar has a method `add`, that takes a quantity and a unit of time, and a method called `compareTo`, that takes another calendar. You should be using those.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.lang.Math.abs (
    ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
        LocalDate.parse( "2017/01/23".replace( "/" , "-" ) ) ,
        LocalDate.parse( "2017/02/14".replace( "/" , "-" ) ) 
    )
) > 3L
```

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, and such).

Your input strings almost comply with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for date-only values: YYYY-MM-DD. To fully comply, replace the slash characters with hyphen characters.

```
String inputA = "2017/01/23".replace( "/" , "-" ) ;
String inputB = "2017/02/14".replace( "/" , "-" ) ;
```

The java.time classes by default use the standard formats when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ldA = LocalDate.parse( inputA );
LocalDate ldB = LocalDate.parse( inputB );
```

The rest of your Question does not make sense as it tests for +/- three  milliseconds which cannot ever be true between dates. Apparently you meant to check for a count of days. For that, use the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

```
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ldA , ldB );
```

If the second date actually occurs *before* the first date, the result is a negative number. You seem to want to test for either case, using a tolerance of ±3. Use the [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class’ [`abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-long-) method to test absolute value of our result.

The [`ChronoUnit.DAYS.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method returns a `long` primitive. So our test comparing that result to our limit of three must match that type. Note the use of the `L` to indicate that `3L` is a primitive value of three of type `long`. The compiler might upgrade the default of `3` from `int` (32-bit) to `long` (64-bit), but I prefer to be explicit by using `3L`.

```
if( abs( daysBetween ) > 3L ) { … }
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
public long diff(String start, String end) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(start, dtf);
    LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(end, dtf);
    Duration duration = Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2);
    return Math.abs(duration.toMillis());
}
```